# How can be copied the data showed in an frx report on screen?

Tags: export, visual-foxpro

I have a exe based on VFP9, and I'm looking to copy the data that appears on the screen when a large report (200+ pages) is generated, since the option to save it has been disabled. (when you hit ctrl+F3).

I would like to export the data to a txt, csv or xls file.

I don't have the project files, only the exe and some dlls.

There is a folder called reports that I'm guessing should contain the report files, but it is empty.

Can this be done from within the VFP9 IDE?

Comment: Do you have the right to this data? The fact that the ability to save the report has been disabled makes me wonder whether you're using pirated software.

Comment: Yes, since the developer left us without support.

Comment: And the data is ours.

Comment: Run a query to retrieve the data that report is based on. Then you can export it as you wish.

Comment: Its the idea, but when running the application report I dont have acces to a command line or console of vfp and from within the vfp I dont know how to launch it. Im not used to this language and ide.

Comment: Don't have you an option to sent it to the printer? in this case you could save as pdf

Comment: It has the button to print (after you press Alt+F3) but it is disabled.